# value $scope is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have 2 files. First one :

```
<script>
var demo=angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('scoresCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('http://localhost/scores').then(function(response) {
     $scope.scores = response.data;         
    });
    });
</script>
```

Another file index.html

```
 <head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scoresCtrl.js"></script>
     <script> 
            function run(){ 
                var data=angular.element(document.getElementById("scoresBodyId")).scope().scores;
                alert(data);
            }
     </script></head>

<body  onload="run()" id="scoresBodyId" ng-controller="scoresCtrl" >
</body>
```

When I tried to display  **alert(data)** , I got **undefined** 
but when I replace  **onload**  by  **onclick**  , after Clicking I obtained my value.
 I would like to use onload. Thanks for your explanation and your help.

Comment: $http.get is an async call

Comment: did you add ng-app directive to your html tags??

Comment: getting values from scope using `angular.element` is a bad practice unless the only way

Comment: yes ,  <html ng-app="demo">

Comment: And do you really have an issue with "$scope is undefined" ?

Comment: yes , but when I used onclick , I obtained my result after clicking.

Comment: From your code, it seems that you didn't inject `$scope` or `$http` in your controller. You need something like this: `demo.controller('scoresCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){ ...`.

Comment: Hi @eminlala I tried this. It didn't change anything in my result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `onload` to `ng-init` to call your function on body

Controller

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('scoresCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.run = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost/scores').then(function(response) {
            $scope.scores = response.data;
            alert($scope.scores);
        });
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scoresCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-init="run()" id="scoresBodyId" ng-controller="scoresCtrl">
</body>
```